# Unicode emoji as string to emoji in Python3

Tags: python, string, unicode

I'm reading a file with a lot of Unicode code (emojis) such as U+1F49B. What I want to do is do something like `"\U0001F49B"`, but without writing, I just have the code like this in a variable `"U0001FA77"`

```
class Emoji:
    def __init__(self, tipo, codigo):
        self.tipo = tipo
        self.codigo = self.convertirCodigo(codigo)

    def convertirCodigo(self, codigo):
        nuevoCodigo = codigo.replace("+", "000")
        nuevoCodigo.replace("\n", "")
        return nuevoCodigo

    def __str__(self):
        return self.codigo
```

I have a class that contains all the "emojis", I want to know if there's a way to show the emoji itself with a variable. Instead of that I just get `"U0001FA77"` as output.

Comment: Beside the point, but `nuevoCodigo.replace("\n", "")` on its own doesn't do anything cause the result is never saved. And FWIW, if you wanted to remove all whitespace (might as well, probably), you could do `nuevoCodigo = nuevoCodigo.strip()`.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go from `'U+1F49B'` to `chr(int('1F49B', 16))`, for example:

```
codigo = 'U+1F49B'
hex_ = codigo.removeprefix("U+")
codepoint = int(hex_, 16)
character = chr(codepoint)
print(character)
```

Output:

**Note**: [`str.removeprefix()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) was added in Python 3.9. You could just as well do `.replace("U+", "")` or something else, but I prefer this because it's more strict about the input.